# Change Entrykey with \DeclareSourcemap

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I wanted to ask if it's possible to change the entrykey of a specific citation using the `\DeclareSourcemap` command. The following MWE won't work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber,style=chem-acs,articletitle=true,doi=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{citea,
author = {McClane, John},
journal = {20th Century Fox},
pages = {1--10},
title = {{Die Hard}},
volume = {1},
year = {1988}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
          \map{
      \perdatasource{mwe.bib}
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=citea, replace=citeb]
       }
        }
}

\begin{document}
Yippee Ki Yay, motherf****r.\cite{citeb}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

changing the journal field with `\step[fieldsource=journal, match=20th Century Fox, replace=The Walt Disney Company]` works, however, it does not seem to work for the entrykey field. Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAICS you can not modify the `entrykey` field. I'm not quite sure because I don't know exactly at which point the sourcemap happens, but I have a hunch that it would be impossible for your MWE to work as is: Biber only parses those entries that have been `\cite`d or `\nocite`d. In the MWE `citeb` is cited, but not `citea`. If Biber never processes `citea` it will never find out that `citea` is actually supposed to be `citeb`, but it has no reason to process `citea`. (I tested with `\nocite{*}`, which would at least force Biber to look at `citea`, but it did not become `citeb`.)

Comment: ... You could open a bug report/feature request at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues if you really need this feature. I personally find it quite counter-intuitive and have a few reservations about the technicalities behind this. An alternative could be the use of the `ids` field. Add `ids = {citeb},` to the entry `citea`. Then it can be cited as `citeb` in the document. I did not manage to do that in a sourcemap either (again I assume it has to do with the order of processing, but I'm not quite sure).

Comment: I will try to add a `ids` field. Do you know how I can tell `\DeclareSourcemap` to add a field (like `ids`) to a specific citation only?

Comment: I did some experimenting and as far as I can see you can't use a source map to add the `ids` field. The problem is (I'm not exactly sure here) that the field `ids` needs to be resolved *before* source maps are applied. So I see no chance for your attempt if you need on the fly source maps.

Comment: @moewe , What about creating an `entryclone`?

Comment: @DavidPurton Sounds like it could work. If you write an answer I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible option using an `entryclone`. I then added `dataonly` to the options of `citea` to make sure it never appears. (Though your exact use case isn't clear me.)

Note that you must use `journaltitle` instead of `journal` for this work.

You still have to `\nocite{citea}`. But you have to do this for the source map to work on it anyway.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber,style=chem-acs,articletitle=true,doi=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{citea,
author = {McClane, John},
journaltitle = {20th Century Fox},
pages = {1--10},
title = {{Die Hard}},
volume = {1},
date = {1988}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=citea, final]
      \step[entryclone={citeb}]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={dataonly}]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{citea}
Yippee Ki Yay, motherf****r.\cite{citeb}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]